# Issues with CytoScape - 3.10.0 - Not Launching - error installing bundle listed in startup.properties with url:

Tags: cytoscape

Looking for some advice, seeing an issue with Cytoscape version 3.10.0 not launching on Windows 10, running Adoptium jdk-11 , but have also tried jdk-17.0.8+7

In the Cytoscape output file I have the following error Error installing bundle listed in startup.properties with url: mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.3.7 and startlevel: 15

I have tried other versions of the adoptium java environments, also tried the test from cytoscape that gets the following output :

Cytoscape test:
'jvmVariant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

### Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Windows

Target Cytoscape version: 3.9.0

Your Windows version is:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3086]

Java is installed

### More details on Java

openjdk version "11.0.20" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.20+8 (build 11.0.20+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.20+8 (build 11.0.20+8, mixed mode)

Your system is 64 bit

Your JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-11.0.20.8-hotspot\bin

Your Java Major version is 11
Your Java version is at least version 11 as required

Your Java version is no higher than version 11 as required

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0 50642    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0

The "app" store at https://apps.cytoscape.org is reachable

### Summary

Success! You are ready to run Cytoscape 3.9.0

Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we are aware of this issue.  The latest versions of Java 11 and Java 17 introduced a breaking change that breaks zip files.  There are two workarounds:

1. Downgrade to Java 17.0.7 (the change was introduced in 17.0.8)
2. Do export EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS="-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true"  before launching.

#2 would be very difficult in a Windows environment (you would need to edit the .bat file and only launch from that).  I would recommend doing #1.  We are working on a fix and will release a new version (3.10.1) shortly.